# Python Selenium: I am getting element is not attached to the page document error

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to build a scraper using selenium package for python but I am getting this error:

```
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

I am using google colab.
My code is:

```
import selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
titles=[]
for link in links:
  driver.get(link)
  data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@class = "question-hyperlink"]')
  titles.append(data[0].text)
```

The error is in line `data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@class = "question-hyperlink"]')`

I was told to try exception handling but I am unable to implement it. Please help me with how can I implement it.

Comment: exception handling is `try` and `except` around what you want to catch - have a read here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html   - if you have a go and post a code with a specific error we can help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems synchronization issue while iterating list of links.
Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and then iterate and store in the list.

Use try..except block to handle.

**Code**:

```
titles=[]
for link in links:
  driver.get(link)
  try:
      data=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//a[@class = "question-hyperlink"]')))
      for d in data:
        titles.append(d.text)
  except:
      print("element not found")
      continue
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Any way to speed up? because size of link is 7000+

Answer (score 0):

Before you attempt to interact with the desired elements you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
import selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
titles=[]
for link in links:
  driver.get(link)
  data = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class = 'question-hyperlink']")))
  titles.append(data[0].text)
```